# Stratified train-test splitting a Tensorflow dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, train-test-split, imbalanced-data

I am currently working with a quite large image-dataset and I loaded it using `ImageDataGenerator` from `tensorflow.keras` in python. As the classification of my data is very imbalanced I wanted to do a stratified train-test-split to possibly achieve a higher accuracy.

I know how to do a simple random train-test-split using `ImageDataGenerator` but I couldn't find any equivalent of the stratified train_test_split you can do in `sklearn`.

Is there any way to stratified train-test-split a `tensorflow.data.Dataset`?
And if not, how do you deal with large imbalanced datasets?
I would very appreciate your help!

Here is the relevant code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
dataset = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    path_images, 
    target_size=(ImageHeight, ImageWidth), 
    color_mode='rgb', 
    class_mode='sparse', 
    batch_size=BatchSize, 
    shuffle=True, 
    seed=Seed,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

flow(
x,
y=None,
batch_size=32,
shuffle=True,
sample_weight=None,
seed=None,
save_to_dir=None,
save_prefix='',
save_format='png',
ignore_class_split=False,
subset=None
)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32101392)